# Reset a setInterval times in AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have the following code using AlpineJS:

```
<div 
  x-data='{ images: imagesArray, index: 0 }' 
  x-init="setInterval(() => index = (index < imagesArrayLength - 1) ? index + 1 : 0, 10000)">

  <!-- Other code -->

  <button x-on:click="index = 3"></button> 

</div>
```

I am displaying the first image in the array and change to the next after a time interval.

I can also change to another image clicking a link:

```
<button x-on:click="index = 3"></button>
```

Is it possible to reset the timer when this button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can save the *interval id* and reset it before you (re)start it.
You can add a function to your *Alpine object* wich does all the work and then you can call it whenever you need to restart the timer:

```html
<div
    x-data='{ images: imagesArray, index: 0,  intervalId: null,
      resetTheInterval: function() {clearInterval(this.intervalId); this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.index = (this.index < this.images.length - 1) ? this.index + 1 : 0, 10000)}
    }'
    x-init="resetTheInterval()"
>

    <!-- Other code -->

    <button x-on:click="index = 3; resetTheInterval()"></button>

</div>
```

The Alpine object is now a bit verbose, consider moving the *Alpine data* as external code (<script>)